# Array Initialization in Expect script

Tags: shell

How do you initialize an array in expect-send script? We can initialize a variable using
set Variable_name value.  Likewise how can an array be initiated in expect-send script?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean array as in associative array, not array as in C-like numerically-indexed list. You use the [`array set`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/array.htm) command:

```
array set varname {key1 val1 key2 val2 key3 val3 ... ...}
```

Since the contents of braces are not evaluated by Tcl (hence by expect), you can make it pretty if you want

```
array set varname {
    key1 val1
    key2 val2
    .... ....
}
```

You can also assign the array elements directly:

```
set varname(key1) val1
set varname(key2) val2
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that unlike **set** used to set a variable, `array set` works differently:

In the same tclsh:

```
% array set a {key1 val1 key2 val2}
% parray a
a(key1) = val1
a(key2) = val2

#This will not delete the content of the array:
% array set a {}
% parray a
a(key1) = val1
a(key2) = val2

#This will add new key-value pair:
% array set a {key3 val3}
% parray a
a(key1) = val1
a(key2) = val2
a(key3) = val3

#Array keys are unique:
% array set a {key1 val1 key2 val2}
% parray a
a(key1) = val1
a(key2) = val2
a(key3) = val3

#To unset the entire array content:
array unset a *

#To unset the array:
array unset a
```